# How can I use jQuery to add textlabels inside textfields and when a user clicks inside the input field the text disappears like here on SO

Tags: jquery

How can I use jQuery to add text labels inside input fields and text fields and when a user clicks inside the input field the text disappears like here on stackoverflow.

Looking for examples or tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#textboxid').focus(function() {
    if(this.value == default_value) {
        this.value = '';
    }
});
$('#textboxid').blur(function() {
    if(this.value == '') {
        this.value = default_value;
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 - This is correct, though it should be pointed out if you're not *already* using jQuery, the vanilla JS version is just as easy here, might consider adding it to your answer :)